# How to Resize Unicode Characters via CSS

Tags: html, css, unicode

I have the following `ul`, which produces a square bullet that (without modification) is *very* slightly larger than the default square bullets in HTML.

```
li:before {
  content: "\25a0";
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;          
}
```

**Problems:**

1. I want to ***significantly*** increase the size of the square *unicode-generated* bullet.
2. Also, the bullet is aligned to the bottom of the text instead of **center aligned** to the text.

Any clues on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: yep. give me one sec.

Comment: The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/byUpB/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add the below CSS properties to `li:before`

```
font-size: 128px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

You can change the `128px` to any size you want.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byUpB/2/)

Answer (score 5):

Please note that at least your fiddle behaves totally different across browsers !

You did not specify a font-family for the Unicode part.
In the fiddle many Unicode characters will appear larger in Firefox, IE and Edge. Probably in all non-webkit browsers.

Add e.g.

```
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Arial Unicode MS";
```

everywhere you want to use Unicode characters crossbrowser ...

You can read more about the differences in detail here:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/unicode-for-a-multi-device-world/

Answer (score 3):

Add `font-size:12em;` to your CSS. Since you're using a unicode character it's technically part of a font; because of this, you can use `font-size` to change the size of the bullet. Also, as Raptor pointed out, use `vertical-align: middle` to line up the text as before