# Unicode character alignment

Tags: html, css, unicode

I want to display a unicode character centered in a button, see

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
    <button class="btn btn-tool">
      <span></span>
    </button>
  </div>

span:before {
  font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750346/how-to-resize-unicode-characters-via-css), I tried to resize the character using

> font-size

and

> vertical-align.

As can be seen in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8skps53/6/.), the alignment is not as desired (character centered both horizontically and vertically).
Can you please assist?

Comment: Remember to mark the correct answer by clicking the check mark left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several methods available for horizontal and vertical centering. Here's what I would prefer:

```css
.btn.btn-tool {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; /* inserted height and width only for demonstration purposes */
  width: 80px;
}
span:before {
  font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 3em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-tool">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g8skps53/8/

Comment: If I understand correctly, your code is saying - set the unicode character as `position: absolute` then `top: 50%` is saying bring it down 50% of the parents height, then `tranform: translateY(-50%)` is saying shift it back up 50% of the unicode chars own height, so that if the parent button changes size the unicode char will adjust accordingly. thats nice and could be used in different situations too...

Comment: You got it exactly right. This is one of the standard methods for vertical centering (which used to be a pain the ass for 25 years now).

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the vertical-align and instead just modify the line-height  https://jsfiddle.net/39a4grvh/

```
.btn-tool {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  color: #a19d9d;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

span:before {
  font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 3em;
}
```